# How many characters can be sent at a time with NFC Messages?

Tags: android, nfc

Assuming that we will use UTF-8 encoding, and NDEFRecord types Text or URI:

How many characters can be placed into a NDEF Record with type TEXT? Is there any character limitations?

What about URI type NDEF Records, any limits on the size of characters the URI can be?

Comment: Anything wrong with Kamen's answer Oscar? Don't forget to accept if you are happy with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The NDEF specification limits the NDEF payload to (2^32 - 1) bytes so this should not be a problem to make a large Record. Just the real limitation comes from the hardware on which you want to store it. For example MIFARE Standart has 1K or 4K version. So check the memory capabilities of your card.

Comment: Yes the main limitation is the tag to which you are writing.

Answer (score 3):

When you write "can be sent" in your question, I assume you mean "can be sent between phones". (For writing to a tag, the tag's memory capacity is the main limitation. The `Ndef` technology method [`getMaxSize()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/Ndef.html#getMaxSize%28%29) will return the maximum NDEF message size that will fit on the tag, as noted in another answer here. The biggest tags I have come across can store 32kB of NDEF data, but this takes inconveniently long to be read.)

A single NDEF message can consist of multiple NDEF records. So there is no real theoretical maximum to the size of a single NDEF message. Using the Chunk Flag in an NDEF record, even allows to extend the payload of a single record beyond the boundary of (2^32-1) bytes by distributing it over multiple record "chunks".

For sending peer-to-peer NDEF messages between phones, using [`setNdefPushMessage`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#setNdefPushMessage%28android.nfc.NdefMessage,%20android.app.Activity,%20android.app.Activity...%29), what is realistic also depends on how much time will be spent on sending/receiving the data. NFC is very suitable for exchanging small amounts of data, but becomes inconvenient if phones need to be held together for many seconds to perform the data transfer. So in practice, you should probably not go beyond about 1kB.

BTW: For sending very long URLs, I would recommend the use of a URL shortening service, such as http://goo.gl/

Answer (score 0):

You need to query the NDEF interface for the Maximum size.  It is not guaranteed to be consistent across all devices.

Check Here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/Ndef.html